# How can I add underlined words in a line of text in a word header object?

Tags: c#, ms-word, underline

I need to add underlined column headers to the header objects in a document. I am using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

The pertinent parts of the code look like this...

```
foreach (Word.HeaderFooter header in wordSection.Headers)
{
    int[] fiscalYears = RetrieveFiscalYears(docProfile);
    string paddingFY = new String(' ', 8);
    Word.Paragraph colParagraph = wordRng.Paragraphs.Add();

    int year;
    for (int i = fiscalYears.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        year = fiscalYears[i];
        colParagraph.Range.InsertAfter(MARKUP_WORD_TAB);
        //begin underline
        colParagraph.Range.InsertAfter(paddingFY + year.ToString() + paddingFY);
        //end underline
    }
    colParagraph.Range.InsertAfter(MARKUP_WORD_TAB);
    colParagraph = wordRng.Paragraphs.Add();
    colParagraph.set_Style(wordDoc.Styles["ColumnHeadings"]);
}
```

Basically it needs to look similar to ...

```
 Expended          Estimated          Budgeted
   2015               2016              2017
 ---------         ----------         --------
```

In the body of the document, my for loop looks like

```
foreach (int year in fiscalYears)
{
    wordApp.Selection.TypeText(MARKUP_WORD_TAB);
    wordApp.Selection.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
    wordApp.Selection.TypeText(paddingFY + year.ToString() + paddingFY);
    wordApp.Selection.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
}
```

But the when I use the selection object, it writes to the body of the document, not to the header/footer objects. I might be able to get around this by using the SeekHeader and making it the focus, but that offers its own challenges...
I've tried using the colParagraph.Range.Font.Underline object, but that underlines the entire line, not just the words that make up the column headings.
I've tried using a find object, but the execute doesn't find the text for some reason.

Appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: It can certainly be done, I'm just not sure whether putting this information in a page header is the best approach...? Is there a reason you're not using tables with repeating header rows?

Comment: Well the first reason is I'm modifying code that already writes a very large document with several highly formatted sections, I just need to add headers to the second page header object (first page headers are blank because of continuous sections).  Word (and Excel) neither one handle lots of formatted text in cells very well.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the set style above the for loop and set a new range based on the paragraph range and move its start and end positions.  Then apply the underlining to the new range. 
 So now it looks similar to ....

```
colParagraph.Range.InsertAfter(MARKUP_WORD_TAB);
colParagraph = wordRng.Paragraphs.Last;         //reset the range to include the tab so the style can be applied.
colParagraph.set_Style(wordDoc.Styles["ColumnHeadings"]);

int year;
int start = colParagraph.Range.Text.Length - 1;
string yrHeading = string.Empty;
Word.Range underlineRange = null;
for (int i = 0 ; i < fiscalYears.Length; i++)
{
    year = fiscalYears[i];
    colParagraph = wordRng.Paragraphs.Last;         //reset the range to include the last fiscal year that was entered.
    start = colParagraph.Range.Text.Length - 1;

    colParagraph.Range.InsertAfter(yrHeading);
    colParagraph.Range.InsertAfter(MARKUP_WORD_TAB);
    underlineRange = colParagraph.Range.Duplicate;
    underlineRange.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, start);
    underlineRange.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -2);           //-2 = /t/r for tab & paragraph characters
    underlineRange.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
}
colParagraph = wordRng.Paragraphs.Add();
```